# Git commands in pre-commit hook don't return correct output

Tags: git, bash, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to enforce some rules using git's pre-commit hook. I want to check for any unstaged changed files using `git diff --name-only`, and if any exist, fail the commit process. However, in my `pre-commit` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
pwd
test=$(git diff --name-only)
echo "Untracked files: $test"
exit 0
```

`git diff --name-only` returns an empty string. If I run that command in a shell, I see the unstaged files changed. Changing the command to use `sudo` seems to behave correctly, leading me to believe that the issue is around user permissions. However `chmod u+x`ing or even `chmod 777`ing the `pre-commit` file doesn't seem to affect the results.

I have also created a similar bash file inside of the git repo root to test the command, and it works as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I will note, though, that `git diff --name-only` compares the index to the work-tree, so it finds modified-but-unstaged files (which your text says is what you want). So far so good, but then you do: `echo "Untracked ...` which has the word *untracked* rather than *unstaged*.

Comment: @torek good catch, it's meant to say unstaged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `git diff --staged` to show staged files.

And make sure `git commit` triggered pre-commit script execution. Just check first line is repository direcotry when `git commit`.

I have tested your script, it's nothing wrong. So I guess you may note rename `pre-commit.sample` to `pre-commit`?